# Applescript or .sh script to add a bookmark to Chrome in MacOS

Tags: applescript

I am trying to automate the process of adding a bookmark to Chrome in MacOS and therefore need an applescript or bash script that can be sent to a Mac machine in order for this to happen.

The vbscript below works in a Windows environment. Is there a way to convert it to MacOS?

Many thanks for your comments

---

```
    Imports System
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Text
    Imports Microsoft.Win32
    Imports System.Diagnostics
     Module Module1
Dim AppPath As String
Dim PathFileVar As String
Dim TestText As String
Dim Workbench As String
Dim TriggerFound As Boolean
Dim UserProfileVar As String = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("UserProfile")
'Dim lineArray As New ArrayList()
Sub Main()
    'MsgBox("start  " & UserProfileVar)
    AppPath = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(UserProfileVar & "\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks.txt") Then
        Try
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(UserProfileVar & "\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks.txt")
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End If
    'MsgBox("before section")
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(UserProfileVar & "\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks") Then
        Dim lineArray As New ArrayList()
        PathFileVar = UserProfileVar & "\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\bookmarks"
        Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(PathFileVar)
        For x As Integer = 0 To lines.GetUpperBound(0)
            lineArray.Add(lines(x))
        Next
        Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
        file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(UserProfileVar & "\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks.txt", True)
        For x = 0 To lineArray.Count - 1
            TestText = (lineArray.Item(x))
            Dim dIndex = TestText.IndexOf("[")
            If TriggerFound = False Then
                If (dIndex > -1) Then
                    TriggerFound = True
                    '************** start inserting my bookmark ***************************
                    Workbench = TestText.Substring(0, dIndex)
                    Workbench = Workbench & "[ {"
                    file.WriteLine(Workbench)
                    file.WriteLine("            " & Chr(34) & "date_added" & Chr(34) & ": " & Chr(34) & "13116611233249308" & Chr(34) & ",")
                    file.WriteLine("            " & Chr(34) & "id" & Chr(34) & ": " & Chr(34) & "222" & Chr(34) & ",")
                    file.WriteLine("            " & Chr(34) & "name" & Chr(34) & ": " & Chr(34) & "xxxx Emp Service" & Chr(34) & ",")
                    file.WriteLine("            " & Chr(34) & "type" & Chr(34) & ": " & Chr(34) & "url" & Chr(34) & ",")
                    file.WriteLine("            " & Chr(34) & "url" & Chr(34) & ": " & Chr(34) & "https://example.com" & Chr(34))
                    file.WriteLine("            },")
                    dIndex = dIndex + 1
                    Workbench = TestText.Substring(dIndex)
                    file.WriteLine("            " & Workbench)
                    '***************** end of insert *************************************
                Else
                    file.WriteLine(TestText)
                End If
            Else
                file.WriteLine(TestText)
            End If
        Next
        file.Close()
        Try
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(PathFileVar)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        Try
            My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(UserProfileVar & "\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks.txt", "Bookmarks")
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    Else
        'MsgBox("file does not exist and userprofilevar  " & UserProfileVar)
        Try
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(AppPath & "\bookmarks", UserProfileVar & "\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks", overwrite:=True)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End If


    Try
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(AppPath & "\Employee Selfservice.lnk", UserProfileVar & "\Desktop\Employee Selfservice.lnk", overwrite:=True)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Try
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(AppPath & "\_crx_bdicdcflgnjilflenkmoicnpflehicin", UserProfileVar & "\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Web Applications\_crx_bdicdcflgnjilflenkmoicnpflehicin", True)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists("C:\In-temp")) Then
        Try
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\In-temp")
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End If
    Try
        System.IO.File.Create("C:\In-temp\InforCRMdetect.txt").Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

End Module
```

Any help is much appreciated,
regards

Answer (score 0):

This AppleScript works for me using the latest version of Sierra.

This will automatically add a bookmark directly to the Bookmarks Bar folder

```
property newBookmark : "https://stackoverflow.com" -- Insert the desired URL
property theTitle : "Whatever Title You Want"
property bookmarkFolder : "Bookmarks Bar" -- The bookmark folder where the new bookmark item will be created

tell application "Google Chrome"
    try
        tell active tab of window 1
            repeat while loading is true
                delay 0.3
            end repeat
        end tell
    end try
    tell its bookmark folder bookmarkFolder
        set theResult to make new bookmark item with properties {URL:newBookmark}
        set title of theResult to theTitle
    end tell
end tell
```

---

Here is a little bit of a different spin…  If you want to add a bookmark to a bookmark folder located within the bookmarks bar folder, this will allow you to choose from a list of the existing bookmark folders, as to where you would like to add your new bookmark

```
property newBookmark : "https://www.google.com" -- Insert the desired URL
property theTitle : "Google"
property MainBookmarkFolder : "Bookmarks Bar" -- The bookmark folder where the new bookmark item will be created
property foldersInMainBookmarkFolder : {}

tell application "Google Chrome"
    try
        tell active tab of window 1
            repeat while loading is true
                delay 0.3
            end repeat
        end tell
    end try
    set foldersInMainBookmarkFolder to title of every bookmark folder of bookmark folder MainBookmarkFolder
end tell

set chooseBookmarkFolder to (choose from list foldersInMainBookmarkFolder)

set saveTID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {","}
set chooseBookmarkFolder to chooseBookmarkFolder as string
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to saveTID

tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell its bookmark folder MainBookmarkFolder
        tell its bookmark folder chooseBookmarkFolder
            set theResult to make new bookmark item with properties {URL:newBookmark}
            set title of theResult to theTitle
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: The edit you've made doesn't really fix the code you first posted. That is, because of how you've edited the code, you've failed to make sure `window 1` exists if Google is running without a window open when your now edited code runs. You'll need to edit it again to account for `error "Google Chrome got an error: Can’t get window 1. Invalid index." number -1719 from window 1` when your current code is run when Google Chrome is open without a window.

Comment: On the script above where you said "Here is a little bit of a different spin"  how could you add the bookmark to a bookmark folder that presently sits on the bookmark toolbar WITHOUT a pop up asking "pick a bookmark folder to put it in?" 
So in other words i just want to add the url to a bookmark folder that exists without a pop up to the user?
Is there a way to add this "silently" whether the browser is open or not?

Many thanks

Comment: @sql1 This was the point of creating the “choose from list” in version 2 of the script.  I don't know about you but I know, personally speaking, I cannot recall off the top of my head…  the names of the bookmark folders located within my bookmark bar folder.  You could always use version 1 of the script which will automatically place a bookmark into your bookmarks bar folder.  Then at a later time you can always reorganize your bookmarks

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged your question with and mentioned AppleScript, you need to know that in order to use AppleScript directly with Google Chrome, you need to first see if Google Chrome is running before trying to execute any AppleScript code to create the bookmark directly with Google Chrome.

If it's not running, you **must** wait until Google Chrome's *bookmark model* is loaded before trying to add a bookmark with ApplesScript. Or if Google Chrome is running without a window open, you must also code to account for that so it won't fail without a window open.

<sub>*Note: Because the other answer was edited after I posted, I had to change some of the content, **but not the code**. See the edit history if there's any confusion in my edit.*</sub>

The following example AppleScript code makes sure conditions are right so those  scenarios will not happen.

```
set newBookmark to "https://www.google.com"
set theTitle to "Google"
set bookmarkFolder to "Bookmarks Bar"

if application "Google Chrome" is running then
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        tell its bookmark folder bookmarkFolder
            set theResult to make new bookmark item with properties {URL:newBookmark}
            set title of theResult to theTitle
        end tell
    end tell
else
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        repeat until (loading of tab 1 of window 1 is false)
            delay 0.5
        end repeat
        tell its bookmark folder bookmarkFolder
            set theResult to make new bookmark item with properties {URL:newBookmark}
            set title of theResult to theTitle
        end tell
        quit
    end tell
end if
```

Obviously you'll set the *value* of the `newBookmark`, `theTitle` and `bookmarkFolder` *variables* as wanted.

It's not totally clear in your OP how you're going to deploy this however, if not as an AppleScript .scpt or .app, having been saved in Script Editor, then you could deploy it as a shell script by saving the example AppleScript code in a plain text file with a `#!/usr/bin/osascript` *shebang* as its first line and make it executable with `chmod`.

It can then be executed from the command line in Terminal or just double-clicked in Finder.

Another alternative, if Google Chrome is not running, would be to modify the User's Google Chrome `bookmark` file directly, but AppleScript is probably not the best for that scenario.

Comment: @sql1, Ref your now deleted comment "Could anyone advise what needs to be added to the script to add a graphic image (jpg) to the bookmark too please?" Google Chrome assigns an icon for a Bookmark based on the sites _favicon_ the are stored in a SQLite database `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Favicons`. There is a Google Chrome Extension [Bookmark Favicon Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bookmark-favicon-changer/acmfnomgphggonodopogfbmkneepfgnh) that you can use to modify Bookmark icons.

Comment: Many thanks user3439894, I used that indeed to create the icon. Your script works well, adds the bookmark when chrome is open as you have mentioned. This will be deployed by sending a .sh which is packaged and sent to all machines, however, for those machines where chrome is not running this will not be suitable. Could you elaborate on what you pertain to where you mention about ascript not being the best in that scenario?